# Finding equation from a word problem

Tags: word-problem

> Tracy and Kelly take a taxi together so they can split the bill. Since Tracy got picked up first, her share is 4 dollars more than Kelly's share. They also had 2 more charges. They had an airport fee of 4 dollars since they were dropped off at the airport, and also had an extra charge of 10% of their total fare since they were being picked up that night.
>
> If x is the taxi fare each had to pay for the ride, which of the following shows the cost they'd have to pay if they split costs evenly.
>
> A) $1.1x+2.2$
> B) $1.1x+6.6$
> C) $2.2x+2.2$
> D) $2.2x+4.4$

(btw, this is what it says - no typos when I wrote it here)

---

When I tried it, I said this:

T(racy) = K(elly) + 4

$(T + K + 4) 1.1 =$ total cost

$(K + 4 + K + 4) 1.1 =$ total cost

$2(K + 4) 1.1 =$ total cost

And so each would pay $(K+4)1.1 = 1.1K + 4.4$ … but that's not one of the options?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I have made some slight edits to your post to make it look nicer. To see how I did it, click the "edited" button.

Comment: Have you reproduced the *entire* problem *exactly* as it appeared in the source? I ask because the problem, as stated here, is rather unclear.  In particular, if Tracy's share is 4 dollars more than Kelly's, then how can $x$ represent the fare that *each* had to pay?

Comment: @BarryCipra I realized that when I did the question. Although it seems that the shares are uneven, they still split it evenly?

Comment: @Sat I get the same answer as you.

Comment: @BarryCipra This is like going out to eat with a friend and splitting the bill. One's meal may cost four dollars more than the other's but they agree to split.

Comment: It's completely possible that there is a typo in the actual question booklet (and I know, undoubtedly, that there have been many typos before) so that could have happened here. It's kinda odd that, in the answers 6.6 appears (and it's possible that should have been a 4.4)

I just posted it here to see if I had made a mistake somewhere or had misread something obvious. 

Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @JohnDouma, I agree, that detail could just be a red herring. The real problem is that the word "fare" is being used unclearly, in particular when you tack a $10\%$ surcharge onto the "total" fare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of the question is ambiguous and unclear, but I'll take a stab at providing an interpretation.  When Tracy and Kelly arrive at the airport, the meter in the cab shows a fare of $F$, but there is an additional $4$-dollar airport fee, and then a $10\%$ surcharge on everything.  Thus the total cost of the ride is

$$1.1(F+4)$$

so if Tracy and Kelly split the total cost equally (even though Tracy got picked up first), they each pay

$$1.1(F+4)/2$$

Now I'm going to assume that $x$ refers only to an equal share of what the *meter* says the *fare* is, i.e., $x=F/2$.  Under this interpretation, the answer  is

$$1.1x+2.2$$

for each woman's equal share of the total cost of the ride to the airport.

Comment: Hmm, that actually makes sense and works out.

As I understand this: the F(are) is whatever the cab says and with the additional charges, they'll have to altogether pay 1.1(F+4) = 1.1F+4.4. And this means that each would pay 1.1x+2.2 (where x is their share)

Comment: This makes sense to me as well.